# How can I verify if a certain value exists in my array?

Tags: arrays, ejs

I'm fetching from database (MongoDB with Mongoose) a list of "comments" and each comment contains an array of allowed users that can see those comments. How can I verify if the logged user is in that array?

```
      <% if(comment.allowed.length  > 0 ){  %>
         <% for(i = 0 ; i < comment.allowed.length; i++) { %>
             <% if(comment.allowed[i] === auth) {  %>
                    You already payed
             <%  } else { %>
                    <form action="/pay" method="POST">
                         <button class="button-upload">Pay $1</button>
                    </form>                                     
             <% } %>
         <% } else {  %>
                    <form action="/pay" method="POST">
                         <button class="button-upload">Pay $1</button>
                    </form>
          <% } %>
       <% } %>
```

I've done this, but in my  array I got 2 emails : email1@mail.com and email2@mail.com.
The logged user is email1@mail.com, and in my page I got both "you already payed" and that form with button, because first value was true and then the second value was false. In my .js file where I render the page I can use array.includes(value), but here I can't. How can I display only one of those cases? There are many other comments and for each I must verify this that's why I'm not doing it in my .js file, I would lose track of what comment that logged user can see or not.

Is there any equivalent of array.includes(value) that I can use in my EJS file, or any solution to accomplish what I want?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a javascript array question than mongodb.

There're many ways to go about this which i'm going to mention a few of them.

A regular way to go about this is to loop through the array and check if a value is what you're looking for (logged in user).

lets say your array of allowed users is

```js
let arr = ["bob@bob.com", "divine@gmail.com", "email1@mail.com", "email2@mail.com"]
```

and your current logged in user is `email1@mail.com`,

solution 1 (Array.find):

```js
const loggedInUser = "email2@mail.com"
const result = arr.find(value => value === loggedInUser) // This is going to 
// return "undefined" if loggedInUser is not in the array of allowed users.

if(result){
   // Do something
}
```

Your template should look like

```
<% if(comment.allowed.length  > 0 ){  %>
       <% if(comment.allowed.find(value => value === auth)) {  %>
              You already payed
       <%  } else { %>
              <form action="/pay" method="POST">
                   <button class="button-upload">Pay $1</button>
              </form>                                     
       <% } %>
<% } %>
```

few other ways you could check if something exists in an array are:

```js
const result = arr.indexOf(loggedInUser) // Array.indexOf -- Check if the value is not less than zero

const result = arr.filter(v => v === loggedInUser).join(' ') // Array.filter -- Returns the "loggedInUser" value

const result = arr.includes(loggedInUser) // Array.includes -- Returns a boolean
```